# Problema ao executar métodos de uma classe genérica

Tags: c++, qt

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma classe de DAO genérica no Qt, porém quando vou compilar eu tenho o seguinte erro, quando vou chamar qualquer método do meu objeto DAO:

`Debug\debug\main.o:-1: In function Z5qMainiPPc':`

`undefined reference to bool DAO::add<Product>(Product*)'`

`collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

O erro ocorre aqui **`dao.add(produto);`** ou aqui **`dao.remove(produto);`**

Gostaria de saber oque posso estar fazendo de errado .-.

### Main

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));    

    //Teste

    Product *produto = new Product();

    DAO dao;

    produto->setCode("123456");
    produto->setName("Teste");
    produto->setPrice(10.33);
    produto->setUnityMeasure("KG");

    dao.add(produto);
    //dao.remove(produto);

    //Fim Teste

    return app.exec();
}
```

### Cabeçalhos

```
#ifndef DAO_H
#define DAO_H

#include <QObject>

class DAO:public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    DAO();
    template<typename T> bool change(T *entity);
    template<typename T> bool remove(T *entity);
    template<typename T> bool add(T *entity);
    template<typename T> T *find(T *entity);
    template<typename T> QList<T *> *findAll();
};

#endif // DAO_H
```

### Implementação

```
#include "dao.h"

DAO::DAO()
{

}

template<typename T>
bool DAO::change(T *entity)
{
    return false;
}

template<typename T>
bool DAO::remove(T *entity)
{
    return false;
}

template<typename T>
bool DAO::add(T *entity)
{
    return false;
}

template<typename T>
T *DAO::find(T *entity)
{
    return NULL;
}

template<typename T>
QList<T *> *DAO::findAll()
{
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o erro tá na implementação. O certo seria assim:

```
template <typename T>
T* DAO<T>::find(T* entity)
{
    return nullptr;
}
```

E até onde eu sei, classes template precisam estar apenas no header, ou o linker vai emitir erros. E não seria melhor declarar logo a classe inteira como template ?

```
#ifndef DAO_H
#define DAO_H

#include <QObject>

template <typename T>
class DAO  : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    DAO();
    bool change(T *entity);
    ...
    ...
};

template <typename T>
DAO<T>::DAO()
{

}

template <typename T>
bool DAO<T>::change(T *entity)
{
    return false;
}

...
...
...

#endif // DAO_H
```

Obs: Ah, sim. E quando for instanciar uma classe genérica, você precisa declarar o tipo:

```
DAO<QString> dao;
```

Se você mercar apenas o método como template como você fez, o compilador pode deduzir o tipo que você quer passar.

Comment: Dessa forma que vc passou eu tinha implementado tbm e tinha dado o mesmo problema. Eu consegui compilar logo apos que coloquei tudo no mesmo arquivo. Basicamente tirei o arquivo cpp e só deixei o header.